# Showing highchart x and y axis value in a table

Tags: jquery, highcharts, drilldown

I have designed a column drill down using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Now my goal is to show the graph data's in a table format , when the page the loads at the first time it will show the 1st set of data`s in the table , where as when I drill down to second level the table should refresh the data and show the 2nd level data which is shown in the graph.

Comment: Can we see the code pertaining to the first set of data's build?

Comment: yeah sure here it is for stack column with drill down http://jsfiddle.net/Gzsjw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highchart give access to click event for developers. 
For example take a look at the following example.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Click event tells you a lot about which point and series did you clicked on (xAxix, yAxis, seriesName, you can even add custom options to your point to retrieve them through click event). You can retrieve which column the user clicked on and refresh your table according to the data of that column. Since you have the inner graph data after learning the outer graph point, getting the inner data would be much simpler I guess.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the input its was actually my plan A but some reason when i click on a particular position or point i want all the xAxis and yAxis value so that i can easily frame the table under redraw event. but wat i am getting currently is i can just get the data of the particular point i clicked. thats were i am struck up

Comment: you can get the series of the point too. On the event function this.series gives you the series object and this.series.data object will give you the data object of the series. I think from there you can achieve pretty much what you want =)

Comment: Yeah thru this i can get the desired o/p... thanks for your path cubbuk :) var i;
                      for(i=0; i<=this.series.data.length; i++)
                      {
                        
                      console.log(this.series.data[i].category+" Value -"+this.series.data[i].y)
                      }

Comment: its it possiable to change the drilldown level using seprate button..for ex i have created a button in html and navgiate between the drilldown levels.

Comment: Hmm.. you might load the new data set with each click on a button, but I don't see how you can keep the drilldown features of the graph. For example you can load the level 1 data into graph, but then from graph you can not go back to level 0 with such a method.. I think the most useful approach is to use legends of the graph and direct users to use them.

Comment: may i knw your gmail id , i will delete the moment i get it ?